# How to list all files in a directory in puppet using custom facts

Tags: ruby, puppet, puppet-enterprise

I need to get an array of data where the data which will be the list of file names in  a directory. I need to get the file name list in puppet manifest as an input .

I need clear steps for reading the file names in a directory. I checked but those where all not working.

```
Facter.add('listdirectory') do
  confine :kernel => "Linux"
  setcode do   
    Facter::Core::Execution.execute('/bin/ls ${test_dir} | /bin/tr  "\n" " " | sed "s/ *$//"').each_line do |line|
      lines=line
    end
    lines
  end
end
```

I expect to get a return value in an array in `init.pp` of manifest. Any help will be useful!!

Comment: What is the current contents of this fact?

Comment: Provided that you're using relatively modern Puppet and Facter, so that structured facts are available to you at all, I would expect that fact to have an array value.  But I'm not sure what exactly you mean by "in `init.pp` of manifest."  Facts are available as top-scope variables or (in recent Puppet) from the top-scope `$facts` hash.

Comment: If i hardcode the path am getting the list in manifest .pp file but i need to pass test_dir as arguments to this .rb file

Comment: Facts do not take arguments, and they are computed before and outside the context of catalog building.  A fact always reports on the same detail(s) of the target machine's configuration.

Comment: John, 
my scenario is
1.in Manifest am passing a directory path as input 
2.By using the input path i need to list the files in a directory (given path)
3.I need that list to stored in a array variable so that i can use for further process